# CTE multiplying records returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I use CTE to retrieve audit records for any table in my db. For example, I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [customers]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [customers_orders]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customer_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_time] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
);

CREATE TABLE [customers_orders_lines]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [order_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [quantity] [int] NULL,
);
```

My audit table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [audit]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [date_time] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [parent_table] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [table_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [table_id] [int] NULL,
    [action] [varchar](1) NULL
)
```

An entry for the customers tables will also have `parent_table` and `parent_id` columns set to `table_name` and `table_id` respectively. Action can have values of I, U, D for inserted, updated or deleted.

My CTE is this:

```
DECLARE @tablename varchar(100)
SET @tablename = 'customers'

DECLARE @tableid int
SET @tableid = 100

;WITH cteAudit AS
(
    SELECT id, [user_name], date_time, table_name, table_id, action, 1 AS audit_level
    FROM audit
    WHERE 
        table_name = @tablename AND
        table_id = @tableid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.id, a.[user_name], a.date_time, a.table_name, a.table_id, a.action, cteAudit.audit_level + 1
    FROM audit a
        INNER JOIN cteAudit
            ON a.parent_id = cteAudit.table_id
            AND a.parent_table = cteAudit.table_name
    WHERE 
        a.parent_table <> a.table_name AND
        a.parent_id <> a.table_id   
)
SELECT * FROM cteAudit ORDER BY date_time DESC, id_no, audit_level
```

So, I add a customer, his orders and order lines. Action is I for all records. Audit cte retrieves records correctly. When I add just 1 audit record for the customer having action U, the records returned are doubled.

The cte should return all audit records for the customer and related tables.

This [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28115b/1) shows the problem.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you please share other table structure relared to this cte?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a recursive CTE, which [seems to work as designed](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1cc1/11), which, after fetching the anchor row, and then recurses to all children linked to the updated row.

Since the cte already tracks its depth through `audit_level`, if you need to limit the recursion to just the specified table without children, just filter on `audit_level`:

```
SELECT * FROM cteAudit
WHERE AUDIT_LEVEL = 1
ORDER BY date_time DESC, audit_level
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1cc1/9)

**Edit**
The issue with the way you are auditing information is that you have multiple `audit rows` (in your Fiddle example, an Insert and an Update) linking back to the same `live` table reference data via the live table PK, without the context of which version you are referencing.

Meaning anytime you add another `parent update` (as you've done by adding a new 'U' to customer), your recursive CTE will again pull (~cross join) all linked child audit records, irrespective of 'when' they were changed - as above, this seems the design / intention of the audit model and CTE, since in the current incarnation of the data model, you have no way to rebuild the actual version of your parent / child / grandchild graph at the time it was modified.

To restrict the CTE to pull the aggregate root (`customer` and its children `customers_orders` and grandchildren `customers_orders_lines`) of only the data which was actually modified at the time of a change, you will need to change your auditing pattern to include a `version or timestamp` of the changed data.

This version would then need to be included on the audit table as a new field, and this version would need to be included in the join key of the cte (viz `table_name`, `table_id` and `record_version`).

Comment: I edited my question with an SqlFiddle example. It shows the problem.

Comment: Adding a version is not possible because we have audit tables that go back over 10 years. The audit table already has a date_time column, however I don't know if it would work because there might be slight differences in seconds / milliseconds when the records where inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you do not need `UNION ALL` operator in this case.
`UNION ALL` operator dose not remove duplicate `Union` will be not allowd in your query.

```
DECLARE @tablename varchar(100);
DECLARE @tableid int;

SELECT @tablename = 'customers', @tableid = 100;

;WITH cteAudit AS
(
    SELECT id, [user_name], date_time, table_name, table_id, action, 1 AS audit_level
    FROM audit    
)
SELECT * FROM cteAudit
ORDER BY date_time DESC, audit_level;
```

But I think this is not the best n standard way to store audit data for your application.

The best way is to use `Triggers to Audit your data.`

```
On Insert of new Row :
```

you will get one table which is store the information of the last insert that you have done.
You just have to create trigger & take values from that inserted table & insert into your Audit Table.

```
 On DElete of new Row :
```

When some one deletes any records from your table then you will get access to **deleted** table. This table stores the information of last deleted record.

```
On Update of table :
```

You will get access to both `inserted` & `deleted` tables in this case.

Deleted table consist of Old data before updatation 
Inserted  table consist of New data after updation

This is the best link to clear all your doubts & basic concepts about triggers & audit the data.

[Click Here For Triggers Information](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0S4P-a6d5w)

Comment: I'm already using CLR triggers so that the audit table is updated accordingly. This cte is to retrieve the audit records.

Comment: Okay Have you checked with my above query.